# Blender 3 Cycles Shadow Catcher Fail

Tags: shadowcatcher

Cycles Shadow Catcher in 3.0 won't work for me. The shadow appears in the viewport but doesn't render. It works in 2.93 no problem.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be most grateful...

Greenbeetle

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have Shadow Catcher enabled as a render pass, so shadows on shadow catchers are rendered in a separate layer to be used in compositing. Uncheck this so show shadow catchers on the main view layer.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. What an idiot! Thank you so much for pointing that out. I had a feeling it might be a simple error on my part, but I've been looking at the problem for hours. Much obliged to you.