# Shadowcatcher not working in 3.0

Tags: shadowcatcher

I recently updated to 3.0 and the shadowcatcher won't work. Spent a lot of time researching and saw also [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250031/blender-3-cycles-shadow-catcher-fail) but I simply can't make it work. If someone could help me I'd be grateful!
Also, how can I upload my blender file here?

[image: No Shadowcatcher]
[image: With Shadowcatcher]
[image: Render Layer Settings]

Comment: you should at least post a screenshot with all relevant settings so we can see what you did. Or ...if you are lazy, just provide the blend file. But just a "didn't work" is no useful information at all with which we could help you...

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the light sources with new ones and the shadows appeared!!!
It was a simple solution but it took a lot of time to find that out.
I hope it will save some time for others.