# What can cause Shadow Catcher mask to be disregarded by Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadowcatcher

I tried to add shadow catcher to the scene I was working on. I reduced a blend file that I was working on to a simplest scene with a cube and a plane and still couldn't make shadow appear on the plane. Creating a separate file, adding a cube, a plane, the same camera and light setup plus shadow catcher plane allows seeing a shadow and I couldn't figure out what is the key difference that can make shadow disappear.

In both cases I use Cycles with Transparency turned on. Camera and lighting setup is identical in both cases. Shadow catcher plane is just a mesh plane added in a center of coordinate axis with Shadow Catcher Mask enabled.

I'm using Blender 3.6.

Here is the problematic file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/j5Og5er8

Here is the file created anew, same scene setup, same Camera, Shadow Catcher and Light setup, shadow catcher works as expected: https://blend-exchange.com/b/mAzkJK5X

This question is similar to [Shadow catcher not catching shadows](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278384/shadow-catcher-not-catching-shadows?rq=1) however:

1. The version of Blender is more recent.
2. I can achieve catching shadows, but only for a file that I create anew in Blender 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing properties one by one I found one that was to blame in my case and it was due to `bpy.context.view_layer.cycles.use_pass_shadow_catcher` set to `True`! It can stay initialized with the default value which is `False` and that'd suffice in my case.

Hopefully it'd help someone.